# Simultaneous async requests with OkHttp

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

My app is using long polling to keep some local state up to date, but it also needs to communicate with the server while independently/simultaneously maintaining the long-polling connection.

The trouble is, OkHttp blocks any other calls to the server while it waits for the long-polling connection to receive data or timeout.

I've set up two OkHttpClient instances, one for normal API calls to the server, and the other to maintain the long-polling connection.

```
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private static OkHttpClient longPollingClient = new OkHttpClient();
```

I've tried having the long polling client set its own connection pool (separate from the default, shared connection pool )

```
ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool(
    LONG_POLL_CLIENT_CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS, // 5
    LONG_POLL_CLIENT_CONNECTION_POOL_KEEP_ALIVE_DURATION_MILLIS // 5 mins
);
longPollingClient.setConnectionPool(connectionPool);
```

I've also futzed with its dispatcher:

```
longPollingClient.getDispatcher().setMaxRequests(5);
longPollingClient.getDispatcher().setMaxRequestsPerHost(5);
```

But no matter what, calls on the vanilla `client` are blocked by the `longPollingClient`

Note, I'm using separate AsyncTasks for my calls. Does AsyncTask share a single thread in a thread pool? I'm relatively new to Android, so I'm not certain.

Comment: I guess you may be right with your assumption about AsyncTask. Since Android 3.0 AsyncTasks are by default executed on a single thread - according to the API documentation in order to "avoid common application errors due to parallel execution". See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: If you want parallel execution you need to use this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29

Comment: This is a bug. You can work around it or wait for the release. Details here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/1353

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody! Using AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor with AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR solved the problem perfectly.